# Maximum recursion depth exceeded discord.py bot loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I have a reminder function in my bot. It checks every 10 seconds to see if the reminder is now and if it is, it sends a message.

```
async def reminder():
    global reminderDone
    if datetime.now().replace(second = 0, microsecond=0) == datetime(2021, 1, 29, 19) and not reminderDone:
        reminderDone = True
        cnl = bot.get_channel([channel id goes here])
        await cnl.send("@everyone Reminder time")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await reminder()
```

It is first called with `await reminder()` in `on_ready()`. After about 3 hours, I get this error:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "bot.py", line 21, in on_ready
  await reminder()
File "bot.py", line 36, in reminder
  await reminder()
File "bot.py", line 36, in reminder
  await reminder()
File "bot.py", line 36, in reminder
  await reminder()
[Previous line repeated 976 more times]
File "bot.py", line 35, in reminder
  await asyncio.sleep(10)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 480, in sleep
  future, result)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 564, in call_later
  timer = self.call_at(self.time() + delay, callback, *args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 578, in call_at
  timer = events.TimerHandle(when, callback, args, self)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 167, in __init__
  super().__init__(callback, args, loop)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 110, in __init__
  if self._loop.get_debug():
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I assume this is caused because the function calls itself but because it is using `await` it waits for the function to stop executing, which it never will because it keeps calling itself. I can't just remove the `await` though because I need it to send the message (`await cnl.send()`) which is a coroutine. How do I permanently have a loop running to check for reminders without getting the recursion error?

Comment: Do you need to quit the function when the reminder has been sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a loop instead of calling the same function again and again...

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def reminder():
    global reminderDone
    if datetime.now().replace(second = 0, microsecond=0) == datetime(2021, 1, 29, 19) and not reminderDone:
        reminderDone = True
        cnl = bot.get_channel([channel id goes here])
        await cnl.send("@everyone Reminder time")


reminder.start()
```

#### Reference:

- [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [`Loop.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looping infinitely, then a while loop is what you need:

```py
async def reminder():
    while True:
        global reminderDone
        if datetime.now().replace(second = 0, microsecond=0) == datetime(2021, 1, 29, 19) and not reminderDone:
            reminderDone = True
            cnl = bot.get_channel([channel id goes here])
            await cnl.send("@everyone Reminder time")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:** Don't use my answer, use the quamrana one, its simple and fix your code.

Simple, you're calling the `reminder` function from itself, (recursion) but without a stop, then, to prevent the interpreter to repeat infinite times, Python throws this error when you've called the function too much.

### Fixing this

Just add a `if` to your code, like:

```
if foo==True:
   reminder()
```

---

**Edit:** Don't use `stop()`! It just stops loops

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but how do I have a loop running constantly without this problem? Your suggestion will not work because reminder needs to be awaited for `cnl.send` to work. Also if the reminder is further than 3 hours in the future it will exceed the recursion depth before the stop condition is reached.

Comment: You can use this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-handling-recursion-limit/#:~:text=The%20Python%20interpreter%20limits%20the,that%20infinite%20recursions%20are%20avoided.&text=The%20%E2%80%9C%20sys%20%E2%80%9D%20module%20in%20Python,value%20is%20usually%2010%5E4.

Comment: That seems like more of a quick fix than a reliable solution, but thanks for answering